# Pointer to an array of ints

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between:

```
//Example of "Complicated Array Declarations" from C++ Primer
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int (*Parr)[10] = &arr;
```

And:

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int *Parr = arr;
```

<s>Both are pointers to an array of integers</s>. But in order to access the first element of `arr` in the first snippet, I have to do `**Parr` whereas in the second, I only have to dereference once `*Parr`

Comment: No, the second one is *not* a pointer to an array. It's a pointer to the first element of an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first code sample,

```
int (*Parr)[10] = &arr;
```

`Parr` is a pointer to an array of 10 ints. It can only point to such an object. For example,

```
int (*Parr)[10];
int a[10];
Parr = &a; // OK
int b[42];
Parr = &b; // ERROR, b is of the wrong type
```

In the second code sample,

```
int *Parr = arr;
```

`Parr` is a pointer to `int`, initialized to point to the first element of `arr`. But it can point to any `int`.

```
int* Parr;
int a[10];
Parr = &a; // OK, a decays to int*
int b[42];
Parr = &b; // OK, b decays to int*
int c = 42;
Parr = &c; // OK, c is an int*
```

Comment: Would you please explain why I need to dereference Parr twice?

Comment: @EngieOP It is a pointer to an array. So you need one de-reference to get to the array it points to, and another one to get to the element. You can also do `(*Parr)[3]`.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: You could also consider int (*Parr)[10] to be a pointer to the first row of a [?][10] integer 2d matrix. Parr[0] would point to the first row, Parr[1] would point to the second row, and to index a particular integer in a matrix, you could use Parr[row][column].

Answer (score 2):

First one is a 'pointer to int[10]'.

```
int (*Parr)[10] = &arr;  // point to int array

*Parr;   // *Parr == arr 
**Parr;  // **Parr == *(arr) == arr[0]
```

Second one is a 'pointer to int'

```
int *Parr = arr;         // point to the start of array
*Parr;   // *Parr == *(arr) == arr[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way we can have a pointer to an integer,or a pointer to a foat ,can we also have a pointer to array?
The answer is "YES".Declaration of a pointer to an array,however is a little clumsy.

For Example,The declaration int(*q)[4] 
means that q is a pointer to an array of 4 integer. in your Code

int(*parr)[10] means parr is a pointer to an array of 10 integer.

but int *parr=arr is only a pointer to the oth element of arr[10].

So suppose you assgin any pointer to arr[10].
in the second  case doing parr++.the parr will move to location arr[10] form arr[0].
but 
in the second case doing parr++.the parr will move to location arr[1] form arr[0].

So i hope u got the answer.