# C++ pointer to an array of ints

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int main(){
    int a[4] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    int(*b)[4] = &a; //with a doesn't work
    cout << a << &a  << endl; //the same address is displayed
}
```

So, `int(*b)[4]` is a pointer to an array of ints. I tried to initialize it with `&a`and `a` both. It works only with the first.
Aren't they both addresses of the first element of the array?

Comment: You mean "initialize", not "instantiate"

Comment: Pointers have a type; (i.e. they're an address and a type). This doesn't work for the same reason that `int x;  double *p = &x;` doesn't work.

Comment: @P. Danielski: How would you differentiate between "address of the first element of the array" and "address of the entire array" if both begin at the same point in memory? A similar example: `struct S { int x; } s;`. Then `&s` and `&s.x` are the same numerical address. So, what is `&s` then: adress of the entire struct object or address of its first field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to an array of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173733/pointer-to-an-array-of-ints)

Comment: Is `&a[0]` the same as `(char*)&a[0]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually they're not the same thing. Even they point to the same address, they're incompatible pointer types, thus their usages are different either.

`&a` is taking the address of an array with type `int [4]`), then it means a pointer to array (i.e. `int (*)[4]`).

`a` causes [array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) here, then it means a pointer to `int` (i.e. `int*`).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this piece of code

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } // array 
int(*b) = a // pointer to the first element of the array
```

You should know that `int(*b)` is equal to `int(*b)[0]` and `a[0]`.
Therefore, It's a pointer pointing to an integer`(int*)`, not a pointer pointing to an array of integer.

That how type issue arises in your case.

Noted that C is a strong type language. Look at your assignment statement.

```
int(*b)[4] = &a;
```

It takes a parameter of `int(*ptr)[4]`. It means you have to strictly pass the argument of that type, which is a `int *`.

And you are trying to pass a pointer to array of 4 `int` to `int *` . Therefore, they're not compatible in the assignment, even their address are the same.